# Composer autoload path not working

Tags: composer-php

I have this script that use composer to setup the project but for some reasons does not work

```
<?php

include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \LeagueWrap\Api;

$api = new Api($key = "somekey"); // Load up the API
$summoner = $api->summoner(); // Load up the summoner request object.
$bakasan = $summoner->info('bakasan'); // Get the information about this user.

$bakasan = $summoner->info(74602); // same thing as above, just to show that an id will wo$

echo $bakasan->summonerLevel; // 30
echo $bakasan->id; // 74602
echo $bakasan->name; // "bakasan"
echo $bakasan->profileIconId; // 24
echo $bakasan->revisionDate; // 1387391523000
echo $bakasan->revisionDateStr; // "12/18/2013 06:32 PM UTC"

?>
```

you can check here http://70.37.98.151/leaguewrap/tests/test2.php the error I get

```
Warning: include_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/leaguewrap/tests/test2.php on line 3
```

my composer.json is

```
{
    "name": "paquettg/leaguewrap",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "A wrapper for the League of Legends API.",
    "version": "0.6.2",
    "keywords": ["League", "legends", "wrap", "api", "facade", "proxy"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/paquettg/leaguewrap",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Gilles Paquette",
            "email": "paquettg@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://gillespaquette.ca"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "4.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.8.*",
        "satooshi/php-coveralls": "0.6.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
                "LeagueWrap": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

and here folders tree

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script cannot find the autoload file.

Including that file is like any other file: The path must be right, and which path is right depends on whether you are using an absolute path (unusual) or a relative path. Currently you are using a relative path.

Assuming your script is somewhere inside that `src` folder you showed, the path to the `vendor/autoload.php` must at least contain one `../` to go one directory level up - maybe more.

Comment: Silly me. It was only a path problem. . .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its the problem with your Composer Installation.

Follow these steps -

First make sure you have the Composer.json file created with all the dependencies.

Let's say you are creating a project, and you need a library that does logging. You decide to use monolog. In order to add it to your project, all you need to do is create a composer.json file which describes the project's dependencies.

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.2.*"
    }
}
```

**Installation - Linux / Unix / OSX**

**Downloading the Composer Executable**

There are in short, two ways to install Composer. Locally as part of your project, or globally as a system wide executable.

**Locally**

Installing Composer locally is a matter of just running the installer in your project directory:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**Note**: If the above fails for some reason, you can download the installer with php instead:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

The installer will just check a few PHP settings and then download composer.phar to your working directory. This file is the Composer binary. It is a PHAR (PHP archive), which is an archive format for PHP which can be run on the command line, amongst other things.

You can install Composer to a specific directory by using the --install-dir option and providing a target directory (it can be an absolute or relative path):

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin
```

**Globally**

You can place this file anywhere you wish. If you put it in your PATH, you can access it globally. On unixy systems you can even make it executable and invoke it without php.

You can run these commands to easily access composer from anywhere on your system:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Note**: If the above fails due to permissions, run the mv line again with sudo.

**Note**: In OSX Yosemite the /usr directory does not exist by default. If you receive the error "/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory" then you must create /usr/local/bin/ manually before proceeding.

Then, just run composer in order to run Composer instead of php composer.phar.

**Installation - Windows**

**Using the Installer**

This is the easiest way to get Composer set up on your machine.
Download and run Composer-Setup.exe, it will install the latest Composer version and set up your PATH so that you can just call composer from any directory in your command line.

**Note**: Close your current terminal. Test usage with a new terminal: That is 
important since the PATH only gets loaded when the terminal starts.
Manual Installation#
Change to a directory on your PATH and run the install snippet to download composer.phar:

```
C:\Users\username>cd C:\bin
C:\bin>php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

**Note**: If the above fails due to readfile, use the http url or enable php_openssl.dll in php.ini

Create a new composer.bat file alongside composer.phar:

```
C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
```

Close your current terminal. Test usage with a new terminal:

```
C:\Users\username>composer -V
Composer version 27d8904
```

**Using Composer**

We will now use Composer to install the dependencies of the project.

To resolve and download dependencies, run the install command:

```
php composer.phar install
```

If you did a global install and do not have the phar in that directory run this instead:

```
composer install
```

Following the example above, this will download monolog into 
the vendor/monolog/monolog directory.

**Autoloading**

Besides downloading the library, Composer also prepares an autoload file that's capable of autoloading all of the classes in any of the libraries that it downloads. To use it, just add the following line to your code's bootstrap process:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

You can also try with below require form -

```
defined('__ROOT__') or define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once implode(
    DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array(__ROOT__, 'vendor', 'autoload.php')
);
```

Comment: I think that composer is installed the proper way, the problem is with autoloading. I can't understand where I have to write that "require ..." in my test2.php file?

Comment: Can you verify if you have the Vendor folder created with all the dependencies inside your project folder ?